# Forecast of $(1-0.5B)(1-B)Y_t=\epsilon_t$

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, arima

> Let $B$ the lag operator and the following model
>   $$(1-0.5B)(1-B)Y_t=\epsilon_t$$ where $\epsilon_t$ is white noise with
>   $E[\epsilon_t]=0$ and $Var(\epsilon_t)=\sigma^2$. Given that
>   $Y_{18}=33$,$Y_{19}=32$ and $Y_{20}=40$, find the forecasts
>   $Y_{20}(k)$ for $k=1,2,3$.

What I did is
$$(1-1.5B+0.5B^2)Y_t=\epsilon_t$$
$$Y_t=1.5Y_{t-1}-0.5Y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$$

So

$$Y_{20}(1)=E[Y_{t+1}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]=E[1.5Y_t-0.5Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t+1}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]$$
$$=1.5E[Y_t|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]-0.5E[Y_{t-1}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]=1.5\times40-0.5\times 32=44$$
For $Y_{20}(2)$
$$Y_{20}(2)=E[Y_{t+2}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]=E[1.5Y_{t+1}-0.5Y_{t}+\epsilon_{t+2}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]$$
$$=1.5E[Y_{t+1}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]-0.5E[Y_{t}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]=1.5\times44-0.5\times 40=46$$
and for $Y_{20}(3)$ it is
$$Y_{20}(3)=E[Y_{t+3}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]=E[1.5Y_{t+2}-0.5Y_{t+1}+\epsilon_{t+3}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]$$
$$=1.5E[Y_{t+2}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]-0.5E[Y_{t+1}|Y_1,\dots,Y_t]=1.5\times46-0.5\times 44=47$$

Is this correct? I don't understand why they gave the value of $Y_{18}$

Comment: I am not familiar with your notation, but in your second equation, shouldn't the first "$=$" be a "$-$"? (You may also consider using a "$Y_{1:t}$" style notation, to cut down on the sprawl!)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Thanks I fixed the typo. I prefer to keep this notation because the book that I'm following.

Comment: I skimmed through it quickly, and it looks fine. Probably $Y_{18}$ was given to confuse you, but you did not fall for it, that's good.